# $_SESSION array does not work, can't add an object to it

Tags: php, arrays

Good morning, I not sure what is happening with my code but I can't find a solution myself. I made a form that whenever you add a new category, it should be displayed in the select element. But when I tried printing it out, I can see that whenever I add a category, the old one gets replaced and not added to an array as a second item. And even then, my form does not get the array from $_SESSION['categories']. Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong?

index.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?> 

<form action="AddCategory.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="categoryName" />
  <select name="parentName">
    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['categories'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['categories'] as $category) {
          echo "<option>" . $category->name . "</option>";
        }
      } else {
        echo "<option>No categories found</option>";
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

AddCategory.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  require_once "Classes/Category.php";

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['categoryName'])) {
      $category = new Category(5, $_POST['categoryName']);

      $_SESSION['categories'][] = $category;
    }
  }

  header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: you can just use `$_SESSION['categories']` instead of `$_SESSION['categories'][] = $category;` in AddCategory.php

Comment: @PHPdev Thanks for the response. I tried many options and it does not work anyway. I will change that to $_SESSION['categories'] because this is how I did it in the first place.

Comment: $category = new Category(5, $_POST['categoryName']); what result you are getting over here in $category?

Comment: @Nirali this is what I get: Category Object ( [id:Category:private] => [parent_id:Category:private] => 5 [name:Category:private] => asdasd )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of storing whole object in session. try to store required value as a string if only one field is required and as a array if more fields are required as shown in below.

change $category->id with id of category as per your db field.

Change in AddCategory.php

From

```
$_SESSION['categories'][] = $category;
```

To

```
$_SESSION['categories'][] = ["id" => $category->id, "name" => $category->name];
```

And change in index.php

From

```
foreach ($_SESSION['categories'] as $category) {
     echo "<option>" . $category->name . "</option>";
}
```

TO

```
foreach ($_SESSION['categories'] as $category) {
    echo "<option>" . $category['name'] . "</option>";
}
```